# SPListItem IsNew Functionality?

Tags: list, object-model

In OOB SharePoint, many of the lists render a "New" graphic when an item is "New".  I found this posting which indicates how to determine this from an XSL file:  http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.com/2010/04/sharepoint-new-image-graphic-show-users.html

Is there a way to get at the "New" functionality through the SharePoint API/Object Model that respects the SharePoint settings?  For example, an IsNew property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the the SPWebApplication.DaysToShowNewIndicator? Could do a comparison with that and the Created Date of the ListItem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.daystoshownewindicator.aspx

Comment: This looks like it will work.  A side note, you must be careful about the RegionalSettings for the web and how the SPListItem returns it's "Created" (and also "Modified") fields. Comparing them to DateTime.Now is probably not valid if your site is accessed by users not in the TimeZone specified for the SPWeb.

See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms197282.aspx and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx

Comment: Very good point Brian, thanks. I've added another Postscript to my blog post about this.